# apache derby does not accept file:/// url to a database

Tags: java, windows, derby

To circumvent a problem that is Windows/Maven/Derby specific, I need to provide to Derby a database URL using the `file:///` protocol. Sadly, this does not seem to work.

If I use the following code, I get a `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for [...]` exception:

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Test {

    public static String url = "jdbc:derby:file:///C:/test/repository.db;create=true";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        connection.createStatement();
    }

}
```

If I replace the `file:///C:` part with just `C:`, it works. Again, due to maven specifics, I can't do that. Am I doing sth wrong? Is derby not able to parse `file:///` URIs?

P.S.: Using the `ClientDriver` doesn't change the picture, I already tried that.

Comment: Why can't you use `jdbc:derby:C:/test/repository.db;create=true`? According [to the manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/index.html) the `file` subprotocol is not supported and the filename needs to be a file _path_ not a URL or URI, so `file:///` can't be used at all

Comment: because we use the database url in maven in relation to the maven project dir. So you use something like ${project.basedir}, which translates under windows to C:\test in the example above. Now this in turn will get interpreted by the derby mechanism as a \t, which is a whitespace character, rendering the path unusable.
This is true for all paths that start with a "t" or an "r" (maybe others, as well, but so far I saw problems with those two).

Comment: Also, where exactly is it stated that file:/// URIs do not work? I searched through the manuals and didn't find that statement.

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefjdbc37352.html "*subsubprotocol is one of the following: directory, memory, classpath, jar*"

Comment: Yes, I read that, as well. I don't see a violation of what I am doing, though. You could interpret it your way, but I would argue it's not actually clear.